# Automatically generating makefiles for a different compiler from an existing makefile

Tags: make, gcc

I am looking for a tool which can generate makefile for Sun CC compiler from an existing makefile , which is actually written for GCC compiler.Is there any tool which does the same? I tried by setting CC on the command line.sometimes it worked. But there are a lot of compiler specific flags , hardcoded in the Makefile. How this can be handled?I could find this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969222/make-gnu-make-use-a-different-compiler. But how this works if the makefile has compiler dependent hard coded flags?

Comment: Typically you just set a variable CC (maybe on the command line) and use the existing Makefile. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to [SE].  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/210654/ash and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/210666/ashal.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: To start off, you could delete the flags that are not recognised by SUN's compiler, while taking notes about what the flags you delete does in GCC. Then you can look for equivalent flags in the SUN compiler documentation.

Comment: Rather than generating a makefile, the sane way to do this would be to write a wrapper called `gcc` that parses its command line arguments and calls `suncc` with corresponding options where possible.